# Is there a suitable platform to practice python NDB queries by defining own ndb models?

Tags: app-engine-ndb

Just like jsfiddle.net for practicing javascripts, html and css,
can you kindly suggest some way to practice python ndb queries in a similar or alternate way.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one I know of is the [Interactive Console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_The_Interactive_Console) in dev_server. That'll probably do what you want.